# A question about fractional polynomials (two)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Firstly sorry for this topic's title..
$${P(x)\over x^2}=x-1 \Rightarrow {P^3(x)\over x^2}=?$$

Comment: Hint: $P(x)=x^2(x-1)$. Therefore $(P(x))^3=?$. Therefore $\frac{(P(x))^3}{x^2}=?$.

Comment: P(x) same as p(x) ?

Comment: @daniel yes....

Answer (score 2):

Cubing both sides of your first equation yields $${P^3(x)\over x^6}=(x-1)^3.$$
Multiplying both sides of the above by $x^4$ gives
$$
  {P^3(x)\over x^2}=x^4(x-1)^3.
$$